# Relationship between columns within a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having MySQL table as follows:

`ITEMS ('itemid' int(10), 'MRP' int(5), 'price' int(5), 'discount' int(2));`

Discount is calculated as follows: `[(MRP - price) % MRP] * 100`

Now if I am updating `MRP` or `price` column then I want discount to be automatically updated. Is there any way I can do it?

I was exploring MySQL functions but wasn't able to come up with something useful.

Comment: Read about MySQL triggers. That should put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it automatically, you should write a trigger.